# npm not installing latest version ngx-bootstrap in Angular 11

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

ng add ngx-bootstrap
Installing packages for tooling via npm.
Installed packages for tooling via npm.
An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module '@schematics/angular/utility/config'
Require stack:

- C:\client\node_modules\ngx-bootstrap\schematics\ng-add\index.js
- C:\client\node_modules@angular-devkit\schematics\tools\export-ref.js
- C:\client\node_modules@angular-devkit\schematics\tools\index.js
- C:\client\node_modules@angular\cli\utilities\json-schema.js
- C:\client\node_modules@angular\cli\models\command-runner.js
- C:\client\node_modules@angular\cli\lib\cli\index.js
- C:\Users\Jaswik\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@angular\cli\lib\init.js
- C:\Users\Jaswik\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@angular\cli\bin\ng
  See "C:\Users\Jaswik\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-2BGEbQ\angular-errors.log" for further details.

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to install ngx-bootstrap in your project from npm using:

> npm install ngx-bootstrap --save

next, you need to add this link to your HTML file

```
<link  href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"  rel="stylesheet">
```

you can also use the ng add command of Angular CLI 11 to automatically add ngx-bootstrap to your project by simpy running the following command:-

> ng add ngx-bootstrap

this command will automatically add necessary files
and also you can add ngx file individually by using this command

> ```
>   ng add ngx-bootstrap  --component accordion
>    ng add ngx-bootstrap  --component alerts
>    ng add ngx-bootstrap  --component buttons
>    ng add ngx-bootstrap  --component carousel
>    ng add ngx-bootstrap  --component collapse
>    ng add ngx-bootstrap  --component datepicker
>    ng add ngx-bootstrap  --component dropdowns
>    ng add ngx-bootstrap  --component modals
>    ng add ngx-bootstrap  --component pagination
>    ng add ngx-bootstrap  --component popover
>    ng add ngx-bootstrap  --component progressbar
>    ng add ngx-bootstrap  --component rating
>    ng add ngx-bootstrap  --component sortable
>    ng add ngx-bootstrap  --component tabs
>    ng add ngx-bootstrap  --component timepicker
>    ng add ngx-bootstrap  --component tooltip
>    ng add ngx-bootstrap  --component typeahead
> ```

and if you want install bootstrap then install it
First, we'll start by installing the dependencies using

> npm install bootstrap --save

Next, you need to install ng-bootstrap from npm using the following command:-

> npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap

> import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

**and if you want to install bootstrap with Angular 11**

> npm install bootstrap --save

There are many ways to do that. The simpest method is by using the src/styles.css file and adding the following code:

> @import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";

if you want to install

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this as well today. I don't have a solution, but someone else filed an issue with the project on Github

https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/issues/6037

Even with the error, ngx-bootstrap seems to have been properly installed for me.